# How to persist Identity Server consent in a database?

Tags: identityserver4

I'm attempting to develop a .NET Core Identity Server but I can't seem to figure out where to hook in to persist consents in a database.  My understanding is that when the use consents to the scopes of an application and checks the Remember Consent checkbox that in only stored in memory by default and if the Identity Server were to restart, the user would have to consent again.  Is there a way to persist consent in something like a database so it can be remembered beyond a service restart?

Comment: I also got the same problem and got someone helped. You can find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63438175/how-to-persist-user-consent-information-in-database-identity-server

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like Entity framework to persist data in the database, 
here is the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) for how to configure EF with Identity Server.